# How to compile razor views in unit test project

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, .net-core, mstest

I'm trying to use [RazorViewToStringRenderer](https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/blob/dev/samples/Mvc.RenderViewToString/RazorViewToStringRenderer.cs) in unit test project. However, when I invoke it, I'm getting errors related to razor compilation:

> One or more compilation references are missing. Ensure that your project is referencing 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' and the 'PreserveCompilationContext' property is not set to false.

The .cshtml files are included in the tested project as embedded resources and unit test project references **Microsoft.AspNetCore.All** It works when I run the web project, but it does not when I invoke it from unit test project:

```
var sp = ConfigureServices();
sp.GetService<RazorViewToStringRenderer>();


void ConfigureServices()
{
    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    var applicationEnvironment = PlatformServices.Default.Application;
    services.AddSingleton(applicationEnvironment);
    services.AddSingleton<IHostingEnvironment>(new HostingEnvironment
    {
        WebRootFileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(applicationEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath),
        ApplicationName = Path.GetFileName(applicationEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath)
    });
    var diagnosticSource = new DiagnosticListener("Microsoft.AspNetCore");
    services.AddSingleton<DiagnosticSource>(diagnosticSource);
    services.AddSingleton<ObjectPoolProvider, DefaultObjectPoolProvider>();
    services.AddLogging();
    var embeddedProvider = new EmbeddedFileProvider(typeof(Startup).Assembly); //needed for mailtemplates
    var compositeProvider = new CompositeFileProvider(embeddedProvider);
    services.AddSingleton(compositeProvider);
    services.AddMvc().AddRazorOptions(options => options.FileProviders.Add(compositeProvider));

    services.AddTransient<RazorViewToStringRenderer>();

    return services.BuildServiceProvider();
}
```

> {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.CompilationFailedException:
>   One or more compilation failures occurred: lfrn3mzv.yfv(4,62): error
>   CS0012: The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
>   lfrn3mzv.yfv(4,81): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is
>   not defined or imported lfrn3mzv.yfv(4,145): error CS0518: Predefined
>   type 'System.Type' is not defined or imported lfrn3mzv.yfv(4,11):
>   lfrn3mzv.yfv(11,11): error
>   CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   lfrn3mzv.yfv(14,36): error CS0234: The type or namespace name
>   'ViewFeatures' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>   lfrn3mzv.yfv(20,129): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TACS'
>   could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?) lfrn3mzv.yfv(20,80): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is
>   defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a
>   reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. lfrn3mzv.yfv(23,67): error CS1983:
>   The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task
>   lfrn3mzv.yfv(23,39): error CS0400: The type or namespace name 'System'
>   could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing...
>
> '_AppCode_Mail_Notifications_SponsorReview_SFNegative_cshtml.ExecuteAsync()':
>   not all code paths return a value lfrn3mzv.yfv(20,18): error CS0518:
>   Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
>   /AppCode/Mail/Notifications/_ViewImports.cshtml(1,7): error CS0246:
>   The type or namespace name 'TACS' could not be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   /AppCode/Mail/Notifications/SponsorReview/SFNegative.cshtml(4,92):
>   error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
>   /AppCode/Mail/Notifications/SponsorReview/SFNegative.cshtml(4,92):
>   error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or
>   imported
>   /AppCode/Mail/Notifications/SponsorReview/SFNegative.cshtml(4,92):
>   error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
>   /AppCode/Mail/Notifications/SponsorReview/SFNegative.cshtml(6,38):
>   error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
>   /AppCode/Mail/Notifications/SponsorReview/SFNegative.cshtml(6,38):
>   error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or
>   imported
>   /AppCode/Mail/Notifications/SponsorReview/SFNegative.cshtml(6,38):
>   error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler.CompileAndEmit(RazorCodeDocument
>   codeDocument, String generatedCode)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler.CompileAndEmit(String
>   relativePath)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler.CreateCacheEntry(String
>   normalizedPath)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRazorPageFactoryProvider.CreateFactory(String
>   relativePath)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.CreateCacheResult(HashSet`1
>   expirationTokens, String relativePath, Boolean isMainPage)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.LocatePageFromPath(String
>   executingFilePath, String pagePath, Boolean isMainPage)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.GetView(String
>   executingFilePath, String viewPath, Boolean isMainPage)    at
>   TACS.Web.AppCode.Mail.ViewRenderService.d__4.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Projects\Tacs\TACS\TACS.Web\AppCode\Mail\ViewRenderService.cs:line
>   42}

Comment: You could use RazorLight for this kind of task https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight

Comment: I've already got working razor rendering. There's no need to use something else. This is just about unit testing

Comment: I believe this won't work because the default engine is too tightly coupled with the mvc runtime. So either you decouple and then mock the engine part or use something that can be run in a unit-test environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core TestServer results in HTTP 500 for Razor views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46464373/asp-net-core-testserver-results-in-http-500-for-razor-views)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would check is that your UnitTest project is targetting the **identical** net.core version as your web project. I say this because even the core types like `String` and `Type` are not being found. This says to me that when compiling-at-runtime (which is what razor does) it can't find the core dlls for what it's trying to compile.

The second thing you might need, is to explicitly add references from your UnitTest project to the *exact* framework dependencies relied on by your razor pages.

Finally, it may be that at runtime your Razor pages are relying on entries in `web.config` for their namespace imports:

```
 <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="A line each for all my other namespaces ..." />
        <add namespace="A line each for all my other namespaces ..." />
        <add namespace="A line each for all my other namespaces ..." />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

In which case, to make it work in unit tests, try removing these lines from the web.config and add the import to each and every razor page:

```
@import Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web
@import ....
```

Comment: I've compared csproj files and project properties of both, the project and test project, but did not found any differences. Besides, it is asp net core, not asp.net